# React - Call request in html file and await for response before initiating the App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I'm have some issue trying to iniate a call in the index.html file and await for the response before continuing the execution.

Please note that this situation occurs on an existing project that I cannot completely modify.

**Here is my use case:**

At the very beginning of starting my app I need to do a request to fetch some configurations. And I absolutely need to wait for the config (even if it takes 2 seconds) as I need some of its values in the index.js, even before calling the .render() method.

There is another trick...

In my src folder there is an object called **appConfig** where a hard coded configuration is set, once I have fetched the remote config I need to assign to this object. Then, appConfig is widely used in the app.

The thing is that the file where appConfig is, is called before index.js (can't figure out why), and as it has already been exported it still has the old values and not the one from the remote configuration.

Here is the code of the config file in .src/consts:

```
const newConfig = window.appConfig || {};

const appConfig = Object.assign({...all hardcoded config}, newConfig);

export default appConfig;
```

Here is a sample of my code in index.html:

```
 <script>
      const getConfig = async () => {
        try {
          return (
            await fetch(
              "some url",
              {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                  Accept: "application/json",
                  "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                },
              }
            )
          ).json();

        } catch (err) {
          throw new Error(`Failed to load app configuration, error : ${err}`);
        }
      };
      (async () => {
        window.appConfig = await getConfig();
      })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
```

**TLDR** => How can I do a fetch request before any logic that is in the src folder is triggerd?

Thank you.

Comment: If you can't modify `index.js` you're in trouble, although that's a pretty absurd restriction and lobbying to change it is your best bet. If not you can modify index.html to dynamically add the script that adds your React code to the page only after the config is loaded, although that will result in significantly worse user experience. If you can modify `index.js` just don't render to the DOM until after the config is loaded (which also removes the need for a global var), not sure why you're trying to do it in the HTML file?

Comment: Does the configuration need to be fetched from a remote source? Environment variables seem like a good place to start.

Comment: @JaredSmith In fact I can modify the index.js file, just not completely change it. I'm trying to call it in the HTML file as once I have the config I need to assign it to an object in a file located in the src folder. And I don't know why, but this file where the object is located is called before the index.js, so it fails...

Comment: @KyleLambert It's currently the case, but the plan is to make it dynamic and configurable from others on a remote platform.

Comment: You're going to need to post more information about exactly what you're trying to do here. I can think of a few potential solutions, but your use case is so weird I'd need more info about the situation before I'd know if any of them could work.

Comment: @Simon what does the configuration do exactly that it needs to be loaded before the app renders. There may be a better way to handle this, but you’ll need to provide more context around what you’re trying to do

Comment: I've updated my post, do not hesitate to tell me if it's not enough.

Comment: @KyleLambert for example it has a property that says if the layout should be "ltr" or "rtl" for arabic people.

Comment: @Simon thanks for the info. I can’t see a reason for wanting to defer react loading while config loads from a remote source. Wouldn’t it be easier to let react load as usual but display just a loading spinner while the config request is still in flight? When the request succeeds you can continue to render the correct layout of your app. Or maybe I’m missing something?

Comment: @Simon you can use useEffect in the App component and branch the layout from there. Make sure to use the dependency array so the config is requested once

Comment: @KyleLambert the issue is that no matters the logic I do in the index.js file, the appConfig has already been set and exported with the old values...